# How to position a row at the bottom of a q-scroll-area in Quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a sidebar menu where I am trying to put my social media section at the bottom of the sidebar but I am struggling to get flex to work and do so. I tried item-stretch on the second row but the issue is the row does not expand the entire scroll area. The closest example which is not quasar per say can be found here https://preview.colorlib.com/#elen

Sidebar Component:

```
<template>
<div class="navigation-links q-pa-lg">
  <q-list padding>
    <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item">
      <q-item-section avatar>
        <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-house" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
      </q-item-section>
      <q-item-section>
        HOME
      </q-item-section>
    </q-item>

    <q-item active clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item active-menu-item">
      <q-item-section avatar>
        <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-shirt" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
      </q-item-section>

      <q-item-section>
        SERVICES
      </q-item-section>
    </q-item>

    <q-item clickable v-ripple class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item">
      <q-item-section avatar>
        <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-envelope" style="font-size:1.25rem"/>
      </q-item-section>

      <q-item-section>
        CONTACT US
      </q-item-section>
    </q-item>
  </q-list>
</div>
<div class="socialmedia-links q-pa-lg text-center column no-wrap flex-center self" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-google" aria-label="google" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow"/>
    <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" aria-label="facebook" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow"/>
    <q-btn flat size="sm" color="primary" round icon="fa-brands fa-instagram" aria-label="instagram" class="float-right q-ma-sm no-shadow"/>
  </div>
  <h2 class="text-h5 text-weight-bolder q-mb-xs">CONNECT WITH US</h2>
  <h6 class="text-subtitle1 text-accent text-weight-normal q-my-none">If you like what you have seen so far we can guarentee you will appreciate our print quality.</h6>
</div>
```

```
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const searchText = ref('')
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .block-wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .active-menu-item{
    background-color: $background-accent;
  }

  .menu-item{
    letter-spacing: .15rem;
    font-weight:500;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }

</style>
```

Layout Component

```
    <q-drawer
  v-model="navigationDrawer"
  bordered
  side="left"
  behavior="mobile"
  :width="$q.screen.width >= 400  ? 400 : $q.screen.width"
>
  <q-scroll-area class="fit q-pa-lg">
    <div class="row justify-end">
      <q-btn flat round icon="fa-solid fa-xmark" aria-label="Menu" @click="toggleNavigationDrawer"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 100%;">
      <div class="col-12">
        <HomeSidebar/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-scroll-area>
</q-drawer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn q-scroll-area's content container into a flex column. You can apply CSS classes directly to the container with `:content-style` prop

```html
<q-scroll-area
  class="fit q-pa-lg"
  :content-style="{ display: 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'column' }"
>
```

Also make the div surrounding the sidebar a flex column with `justify-content: space-between`. The row surrounding it should also have `flex-grow: 1`

```html
<div class="row" style="min-height: 100%; flex-grow: 1">
  <div class="col-12 flex column justify-between">
    <HomeSidebar/>
  </div>
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-hrn3nf?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue) that shows the result

Comment: Ahh interesting I was trying to achieve it with all quasar flex classes but I guess that is not possibly since there is no flex-grow option. This solved my problem so thank you!!!! BTW do I even need the col-12 then and in content-style could we just use the class flex and column to achieve the same thing since their classes in quasar?